# Cakephp3 query with contain returns 0 results

Tags: sql, cakephp-3.0

Here is my query that works:

```
$query = $appointments->find();
$query->where(['Appointments.id =' => '786']);
$query->order(['date' => 'ASC']);
```

This returns 1 result. Now when I want to tie in the other 'belongs to' tables I use this query:

```
$query = $appointments->find();
$query->select(['Appointments.id', 'Appointments.start', 'Clients.name', 'Services.Name']);
$query->where(['Appointments.id =' => '786']);
$query->contain(['Clients', 'Users', 'Services']);
$query->order(['date' => 'ASC']);
```

This returns 0 results, am I doing something wrong?

Here is my my AppointmentsTable.php:

```
 public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('appointments');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Clients', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Services', [
        'foreignKey' => 'service_id'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged what the generated query looks like? And are you ware of how `INNER` joins work?

Comment: Good point, I better inspect the query first. I believe it's debug($query) correct?

Comment: That, or directly `debug($query->sql())`, or check the SQL tab of [**DebugKit**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/debug-kit.html).